# PHP Form post always empty

Tags: php, forms, post

this must be configuration issue and I'm hoping somebody can help. I'm setting up a new project on my localhost and my PHP Post is always empty. Here's the example:

My Form Page:

```
<form id="loginForm" action="/post/login" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and the "/post/login/index.php" page:

```
<?php
var_dump( $_POST );
?>
```

the result:

```
array(0) { }
```

It seems like there's no code issue so what's the problem?

Comment: Do you need to add `value` attributes to each of your `<input>` tags?

Comment: @andrewsi: The value is whatever the user enters, `value` can be used as a pre-set value.

Comment: Does it work if you do `action="/post/login/index.php"`?  Try using a debugger like Fiddler or Firebug to see if your POST is being sent.

Comment: No errors in your logs?

Comment: do you clicked submit and then it redirects to "/post/login/index.php" but didn't shows anything?

Comment: The only error in the log is an undefined index warning...

Comment: I can't believe it - @Rocket Hazmat had the solution with adding "index.php". Really odd as it clearly navigates to the correct page. If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Maybe it's a bug in PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `action` attribute needs to point to the actual script of the page you want to go to.

Try doing this instead:

```
<form id="loginForm" action="/post/login/index.php" method="post">
```

Comment: Great catch, I wonder why PHP isn't sending the post to `index.php` without it being explicitly defined... hmm.

Comment: I'm not sure.  Probably something to with it being redirected and not passing the values to the redirect.

Comment: And I like to hide my server scripting language as much as possible...   so this is a bit annoying

Comment: @Andrew: I'm sure there's a way to fix it, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Update: The following also works "/post/login/". So it seems the filename is required or the trailing slash.